# web application not working on AWS beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i used AWS beanstalk to configure and deploy the web application. AWS beanstalk uses java and tomcat 8 version. i have used backend as mysql and configured same using beanstalk.

after configuring the setup, i got the public url of the application. but when i am clicking that URL, it gives me error that, "index.jsp not found."

i have uploaded the war file using the UI option. The war file is created locally in my dev environment.

i am not getting following:

1: how i will configure my initial pages ? does beastalk reads the web.xml and configure on its own ? where i can get these info ?

2: how i will import the data in mysql database ? how i will create the schema ?

do i need to manually login to EC2 instance and configured everything ? if someone can forward me the doc where i can configure these using beanstalk, that wud be great.

please suggest

Regards,

Comment: if someone can please suggest